# Automatically build library

Tags: visual-studio-2013

I have a Visual Studio project which uses a library (both written in C). Often I make a change to the library as well as the project. Each time I make a change to the library I click on the build button then go back to the project and build that.

What I would like to do is specify something such that when I build my project it checks the library, finds that it needs to be built, build the library then continue to build my project.

Is there a way?

Answer (score 0):

In Solution Explorer, right click on the solution. Select Properties then Project Dependencies. Use the dropdown under Projects and select the project you are building. That will bring up a list of all projects in the solution. Put a check mark on each project that depends on the project you are building. This assumes, of course, that your libraries are also projects in your solution.